# How to Control Background Audio Using Xamarin and iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin Forms and have a Xamarin Forms application which is playing background audio on iOS. In the simulator, I can go to the home screen and the audio is still audible.

I want to be able to use the transport controls on the lock screen like play/pause/fast-forward as well as seeing track title information.

I believe [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/controlling_background_audio) describes how to get an iOS app to interface with the required subsystem in order to achieve the goals I want, but I am unsure how to get it working in Xamarin. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly ,Set it up in the Capabilities of the project to enable the background mode in `info.plist`.
[image]

> in AppDelegate.cs

```
//...
using AVFoundation;
//...
```

in the method `FinishedLaunching`

```
AVAudioSession session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
session.SetActive(true);
```

> in the controller of you  playmusic

```
public void SetLockInfo()
{

  NSMutableDictionary songInfo = new NSMutableDictionary();

  MPNowPlayingInfo playInfo = new MPNowPlayingInfo();

  //image
  MPMediaItemArtwork albumArt = new MPMediaItemArtwork(new UIImage("xxx.png"));
  playInfo.Artwork = albumArt;

  //title
  playInfo.Title = "your song name";

  //singer
  playInfo.Artist = "singer name";

  //rate
  playInfo.PlaybackRate = 1.0;

  //current time
  playInfo.ElapsedPlaybackTime = 0;

  //durtaion
  playInfo.PlaybackDuration = 2.35; // the durtaion of the song

  MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = playInfo;

  UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();                          
}
```

Call the above method  when  you play a new song,and the following method will been called auto

```
public void RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent controlEvent)
{
  switch(controlEvent.Subtype)
   {
     case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay:
          //play the music
          break;

     case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause:
          //pause the music
          break;

     case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlNextTrack:
          //play next one 
          break;

     case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPreviousTrack:
          //play last one 
          break;
     dafault:
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this as answered because all the required elements are here--thanks! But it did require a good deal of additional research and tinkering around in order to get it working. Mainly, in order to get RemoteControlReceived() working, I needed to implement a "renderer" for my MainPage (a ContentPage). I found basic info on how to do that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage

Comment: Additionally, I needed to implement an interface and use DependencyService to "offload" the iOS-specific code in SetLockInfo() to the iOS sub-project so that the main Xamarin forms app can be ported to Android as well.